# How do I use a JavaScript function inside my HTML to get input and provide output?

Tags: javascript

I am using BootStrap 4.

I have the following function:

```
function AcceptInput(text){does stuff}
```

I have a form that contains 1 button and a textarea:

```
    <form action="" class="container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Your Text:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="text"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button onclick="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

I want to use my AcceptInput function in this form when the button is pressed. The text from the text-box needs to be passed as the AcceptInput function's text variable, then, when the function returns a string value, that string needs to be written into another text box as output. How do I do get the strings from the text-box and use the return value in HTML?

Comment: You don't need a separate function to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `AcceptInput` function is called, you can *use*

```
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].value;
```

to get the value inside the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of button from "button" to "submit" - this will emit submit event on the form.

Then you need to add submit event listener for this event - `.addEventListener()`.

You need to ensure that on submisison of form, it does not try browser default behavior to contact server for http request - use `e.preventDefault()`.

then you can take the text, do the transformations using your function and then output the transformed text wherever you want - here I have changed the text to uppercase.

Here is the code:

```js
function AcceptInput(text){
    console.log("dbg1 does stuff", text);
  // for eg: converting to upper case
  return text.toUpperCase();
}

var formElem = document.getElementById("mainForm");

formElem.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var textElem = document.getElementById("comment");
  var text = textElem.value;
  var transformedText = AcceptInput(text);
  var outputElem = document.getElementById("output");
  outputElem.innerText = transformedText;
})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form id="mainForm" action="" class="container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Your Text:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="text"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p id="output"></p>
</body>
</html>
```